# How can I get customData with publish/subscribe on Meteor.user() if I merged multiple services (facebook, password) on Meteor js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-accounts

I'm in troubles trying to get custom data with publish-subscribe methods when merging multiple services for each Account (Facebook, password).

When I do a Facebook login or a password login, I'm getting only the default data for each service, but not their custom. this is the code:

**SERVER SIDE:**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish('currentUser', function userDataPublication () {

  var currentUser;
  currentUser = this.userId;

  if (currentUser) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: currentUser }, {
      fields: { services: 1 }
    })
  } else {

  return this.ready()
}
});

Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

if (user.services) {
  var service = _.keys(user.services)[0];
  var email = user.services[service].email;



  if (service == 'github') {
      if (!user.profile)
          user.profile = {};
      if (!user.profile.name)
          user.profile.name = user.services[service].username;
  }

  if (!email)
      return user;

  // see if any existing user has this email address, otherwise create new
  var existingUser = Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': email});
  if (!existingUser)
      return user;

  // precaution, these will exist from accounts-password if used
  if (!existingUser.services)
      existingUser.services = { resume: { loginTokens: [] }};
  if (!existingUser.services.resume)
      existingUser.services.resume = { loginTokens: [] };

  // copy across new service info
  existingUser.services[service] = user.services[service];

  /*console.log(user.services)
  existingUser.services.resume.loginTokens.push(
      user.services.resume.loginTokens[0]
  );*/

  // even worse hackery
  Meteor.users.remove({_id: existingUser._id}); // remove existing record

  console.log(existingUser)
  return existingUser;                          // record is re-inserted
}
  });

 }



});
```

the `Accounts.onCreateUser` have all the logic to merge Accounts with multiple services and meteor.publish is in charge of publishing custom data on client

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
Index.propTypes = {
  currentUser: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  categories: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('currentUser')

  return {
    currentUser: Meteor.user(),
  };
}, Index);
```

`Meteor.user()` is not getting the custom data that I'm trying to pass to it with publish-subscribe methods.

I'm using Meteor js with react.

Comment: Several comments: (1) your publication is only returning the `services` key. Did you also mean to return `profile`? (2) You don't need to `return this.ready()` in your publication if there is no user, just execute the function `this.ready()` (3) Deleting an existing dupe user? Ouch, that's some serious hackery that will orphan anything that is tied to that previous user ID!!

Comment: thanks for your comments, I'm trying to merge different accounts getting custom data but I cant figure it out how can I do this. I have edited my code with your observations, but I preserved the 3rth one because the same _id is reinserted. I will change that logic if is dangerous for the user.